# Render svg content within <svg> element with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I have a Vue.js component which builds the content of an svg element dynamically. For simplicity's sake, say the content is `<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="60" />`

The component does so by manipulating a data variable named `svg`:

```
  data() {
    return {
      svg: '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="60" />',
      foobar: 'foobar',
    };
  },
```

I have some specific svg element customizations (i.e. width, height, viewBox) in the parent component. How do I render this out in the template in a "raw" form?

```
<template>
<svg v-html="svg"></svg>
</template>
```

will add the svg element which I don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to put the `v-html` on a standard SVG `<g>` (group) element:

```
<template>
  <g v-html="svg"></g>
</template>
```

This doesn't render the 'raw' form of the html, but the `<g>` element shouldn't be a problem